# How to create a text field on a form with an associated dropdown box to select from ( multiple times )?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have been requested to create a text field paired with an associated dropdown box to define it.

For example:
Text Field : Favorite Movie
Dropdown Box Select: Independent Or Commercial

I am boggled on how to do this.
Further more they would like to give the user a chance to do make up to 5 entries.
I was asked not to use InfoPath.

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Comment: You have to create it with HTML+JavaScript: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use a choice field? That would seem to precisely address the use case you're describing...

Comment: @Dan - Thank you. Not sure which Javascript to use.

Comment: @John-M - How would you tie a choice field for each text box filled.
Fill in a text box and then a dropdown select to that textbox  - how does a choice field do that please?